# How to expose a range of ports in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

How can we expose a range of ports in Kubernetes?
My cloud application is using a range of ports when running(40000 ~42000).

How do I specify a range of exposed ports in Kubernetes service yaml file?

Answer (score 9):

One option is to use go-templates to generate the yaml for all of the ports, then deploy that yaml, then use `gomplate` to compile the yaml

lotsofports.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: some-service
  labels:
    name: some-service
spec:
  ports:
  {{- range seq 0 2000}}
  - port: {{add 40000 .}}
    targetPort: {{add 40000 .}}
    name: exposed-port-{{add 40000 .}}
  {{- end -}}
  selector:
    name: some-service
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Then compile the yaml:
`gomplate -f lotsofports.yaml > service.yaml`

Answer (score 6):

Kubernetes services currently do not support port ranges, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23864

Update: As of 2021 there is a kubernetes enhancement proposal field for this requirement: https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/2611

Answer (score 3):

As @Thomas pointed is not supported yet.

However, as workaround you can try to use [Helm templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/#structure-of-templates). 
Create chart with service template and ports in values.yaml file.